# finite vs infinite set function composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

If there is a set $X$ which is finite with $f : X \rightarrow X$ and $g: X \rightarrow X$, then $f \circ g = 1_X$ iff $g \circ f = 1_X$. How is it true for finite sets?

I'm not too sure, but the only way I can see that to be true is if g=f..but I'm not sure how to go about proving it. Where do I go from here (if I am even correct)?

Conversely, does this hold for infinite sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f\circ g=1_X$, then you know that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective.

Aslo, on finite sets, you know that a function is surjective if and only if it is injective...

This does not hold for infinite sets, however.

For example, define $g(n)=n+1$ for all values $n\in\mathbb N$. Also, define $f(n)=n-1$ for all values $n\in\mathbb N$ except $1$, and define $f(1)=1$.

Then, you have $f(g(n))=n$ for all $n$, but you have $g(f(1)) = g(1)=2\neq 1$, so $g\circ f\neq \mathrm{id}_\mathbb N$

Comment: What about infinite sets?

Comment: @user141834 I expanded my answer.

Comment: thank you sir, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A function between finite sets is surjective iff it's injective. So suppose $g(x)=y$. Then $f(y)=x$ because $x$ is the only element for which $g(x)=y$ and it must be $g(f(y))=y$. So for all $x$ $f(g(x))=x$